# Rails Routing - redirect_to yielding period rather than backslash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to use the following line:

```
redirect_to dispensers_url(current_user.id)
```

to generate the following:

```
dispensers/13
```

However I am getting:

```
dispensers.13
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The helper should be dispenser_url not dispensers_url. The latter is for the index action.

Comment: Actually, either with or w/o the .id works.. but still gives dispensers.13

Comment: The only way I can see to fix this is to use render "dispensers/new/#{current_user.id}" and add a dispensers/:id route... However, this is not a good fix for me.

Comment: Do you currently have `resources :dispensers` in your routes.rb?